# What kind of controls are these? They are not a UITableView are they?

Tags: xamarin

Just trying to find out what kind of controls these are.  I am looking specially at the table, I want to put controls in there too.  I want to be able to recreate them in the Storyboard Designer.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is UITableView with Grouped option and opacity set.

Second is UIView with round corners and UIButton.